# How to find invalid hex value in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find invalid Hexadecimal Code in a variable ?

valid:

```
 &#x41;
 &#x4101;
```

or

```
  -amp;#x41;
  -amp;#x4101;
```

there must be 2 or 4 character after 'x' and then ';'

invalid:

```
  &#x41
  &#x4110
  &#x410110;

  -amp;#x41
  -amp;#x4110
  -amp;#x410110;
```

string like this:

```
var  str = "Your done. -amp;#x2022No more late night... &#x202221;no....";
```

i found this regex:

```
str.match(/(?:-amp;|&)#x\d{1,4}(?=[^;\n]*$)/ig);
```

but problem is it doesn't match more than 4 character after x value hex:

```
-amp;#x410110;
 &#x410110;
```

thank you.

(i wanna find like start with -amp;#x or &;#x but doesn't have ";" or after x there are character more than 4 or less than 2)

Comment: `{1,4}` means "1-4 characters". if you want more characters allowed, you'll have to change those limits.

Comment: already tried, but didn't work

Comment: "but problem is it doesn't match more than 4 character after x value hex:"  do you mean that it *does*?

Comment: And `\d` of course doesn’t do the job, if you actually want to find valid hex values … for that, you need to allow `a`-`f` as well. (And maybe their upper-case version too, depending on what exactly you are trying to match.)

Comment: I don't understand. There are an infinite number of matches of invalid hex. Are you looking to find them all, or some partial that _may be_ intended to be hex ? But then, how would you know?

Comment: ok i wanna find like start with -amp;#x or &;#x but doesn't have ";" or after x there are character more than 4 or less than 2. got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invalid hex is in group 1

```
 # /(?:-amp;|&)\#x(?![a-f0-9]{2}(?:[a-f0-9]{2})?;)([a-f0-9]*;?)/

 (?:
      -amp;
   |  & 
 )
 \#x
 (?!
      [a-f0-9]{2} 
      (?: [a-f0-9]{2} )?
      ;
 )
 (                             # (1 start)
      [a-f0-9]* 
      ;?
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: i want to find invalid hex "How to find invalid hex value in a string?"

Comment: Define **invalid hex** ?

Comment: start with -amp;#x or &;#x but doesn't have ";" or after x there are character more than 4 or less than 2.
ex 
  &#x
  &#x41
  &#x4110
  &#x410110;

  -amp;#x41
  -amp;#x4110
  -amp;#x410110;

Comment: The only thing you can do is to match the valid part, everything after is invalid. Want me to show you how?

Comment: There you go, the regex will find invalid hex.

Comment: How did you make out eva ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only allow 2 *or* 4 digits, you can't use a range.

```
(?:-amp;|&)#x(?:\d\d|\d{4});
```

The `(?=[^;\n]*$)` is a non-capturing lookahead that says "after the fourth digit, there must be zero or more non-;, non-newline characters up to the end of the string" which actually doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this to match the valid data:

```
^&#x(\d{2}|\d{4});$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ6oF7/2)**

[image]

The idea is to match the string that contains only `&#x` plus 2 or 4 numbers and `;`

So, if you want to grab the invalid data you can use the discard technique and have a regex like this:

```
^&#x(?:\d{2}|\d{4});$|(.+)
^--- match valid but.. ^---- capture the rest (invalid data)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ6oF7/3)**

That means match the valid strings and discard it, but grab the rest content

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `&#x41`
MATCH 2
1.  `&#x4110`
MATCH 3
1.  `&#x410110;`
MATCH 4
1.  `-amp;#x41`
MATCH 5
1.  `-amp;#x4110`
MATCH 6
1.  `-amp;#x410110;`
```

Comment: i want to find invalid hex "How to find invalid hex value in a string?"

Comment: @eva Sorry the misunderstand. You can easily solve it by using the discard technique. Check my updated answer.